# Dependency 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:3.8.0' not found

Tags: java, maven, junit, mockito

I am using a "MockedStatic" in my tests, but by the execution of method this error is appeared.

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
The used MockMaker SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker does not support the creation of static mocks

Mockito's inline mock maker supports static mocks based on the Instrumentation API.
You can simply enable this mock mode, by placing the 'mockito-inline' artifact where you are currently using 'mockito-core'.
Note that Mockito's inline mock maker is not supported on Android.
```

I have inserted the "mockito-inline" dependency but it looks like Maven can't resolve it. The text of this error is in the article.

I'm using Java 11, Junit 5.

pom.xml:

```
...<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>...
```

Comment: That artifact exists: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-inline/3.8.0 Perhaps more details from the maven output would help.

Comment: They are two different messages. The one you have posted is about your running a test which means your setup is wrong? The title of your post is wrong because if a dependency would have not been found there would have been an error before even compiling and running your test....

Answer (score 0):

As per the official documentation, it is turned off by default

> This mock maker is turned off by default because it is based on completely different mocking mechanism that requires more feedback from the community. It can be activated explicitly by the mockito extension mechanism, just create in the classpath a file `/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` containing the value `mock-maker-inline`.

So I would suggest you to create that file, also you can refer to this section in the
[Official Mockito Documentation](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.2.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#Mocking_Final)

Do remember to add the latest version of mockito-inline maven dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-inline -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```